# Javascript (typescript) Chrome extension, function callback as promises?

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome-extension, chain, arrow-functions

for a code like this

```
let anotherFolder='whatever';
let anotherFolder2='whatever';

chrome.bookmarks.create( {title:'whatever2'}, function( parentFolder ) {
  chrome.bookmarks.move( anotherFolder, {parentId: parentFolder.id}, function() {
    chrome.bookmarks.removeTree( anotherFolder2, function() {
      resolve();
    });
  });
});
```

can I transform it to chain functions? Something like

```
let anotherFolder='whatever';
let anotherFolder2='whatever';

return new Promise(function(resolve){
  chrome.bookmarks.create( {title:'whatever2'}, function( parentFolder ) {
    resolve(parentFolder);
  }).then( (parentFolder) => {
    chrome.bookmarks.move( anotherFolder, {parentId: parentFolder.id}, function() {
      resolve();
    })
  }).then () => {
    chrome.bookmarks.removeTree( anotherFolder2, function() {
      resolve();
    });
  });
});
```

Because I get the error of 'Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'.'

*this is javascript-typescript, but it shouldn't matter here (?)

Comment: `.then () => {` should be `.then(() => {` for a start

Comment: but worst of all ... you're using the Promise constructor anti-pattern and also attempting to call `resolve` on the same promise multiple times (doesn't fail, but does not do what you think)

Comment: Also, according to the documentation I've read, `chrome.bookmarks.create` don't return a promise (unlike the firefox web extension versions that do) ... so, no, you can't do any of that

Comment: `this is javascript-typescript` - are you sure? looks like plain ol' javascript from here

Comment: 1st comment: a typo /// 2nd comment: could you develop more on that? /// 3th comment: so there is no way to avoid the nesting structure? /// 4th comment: it looks as javascript because it is javascript, but written in a .ts file and receiving the ts errors from the editor.

Comment: 2nd: I understand now why you needed a promise constructor, it's just you need more of them!!, 3rd: not easily in chrome, but yes, you can if you wrap each of those functions in a Promise constructor, 4th: fair enough about typescript (I suspected, but wasn't sure)

Comment: Now I get when you say that I'm calling the resolve many times for a single promise and yes, then I'd need more promises! perfectly clear now, thanks!

Comment: For future readers, Gerard, I would suggest you accept @Keith's answer as the best

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to "promisify" any `chrome.bookmarks.*` functions - this, incidently, makes them work the same as `browser.bookmarks.*` functions in Firefox and (eventually) Edge Web Extensions

Promisifying the functions you use

```
let create = p1 => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    chrome.bookmarks.create(p1, resolve);
});
let move = (p1, p2) =>  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    chrome.bookmarks.move(p1, p2, resolve);
});
let removeTree = p1 => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    chrome.bookmarks.removeTree(p1, resolve);
});
```

Then you can use these functions as follows:

```
let anotherFolder='whatever';
let anotherFolder2='whatever';


create({title:'whatever2'})
.then(parentFolder => move(anotherFolder, {parentId: parentFolder.id}))
.then(() => removeTree(anotherFolder));
```

If you are thinking of having your extension available in Firefox (and eventually Edge)

*not tested*

```
let create = browser.bookmarks.create || p1 => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    chrome.bookmarks.create(p1, resolve);
});
let move = browser.bookmarks.move || (p1, p2) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    chrome.bookmarks.move(p1, p2, resolve);
});
let removeTree = browser.bookmarks.removeTree || p1 => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    chrome.bookmarks.removeTree(p1, resolve);
});
```

Then your code above *should* work in any Web Extension

Comment: So the error was ignoring that the chrome.functions didn't return a promise, so that then I have to wrap them into promises. Now it looks very clear, thousand thanks!

Comment: @Gerard - The odd thing is, the firefox (MDN) documentation for `bookmarks.*` functions in firefox Web Extensions (which are supposedly designed to be compatible with Chrome) don't accept a callback, rather, they return a Promise natively. Which makes writing Web Extensions that are Crhome and Firefox compatible just that extra bit painful

Comment: @JaromandaX I think native Promises would be the way to go, but Chrome has been supporting this extension API for longer and so has to be backwards compatible. I'm sure they'll add support soon enough, and in the meantime I wrote a library (open source, contributions welcome) that promisifies the entire Chrome API: [`chrome-extension-async`](https://github.com/KeithHenry/chromeExtensionAsync)

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer is good, but there are libraries that already do this for you, such as [`chrome-extension-async`](https://github.com/KeithHenry/chromeExtensionAsync). That also includes [TypeScript definitions](https://github.com/KeithHenry/chromeExtensionAsync/blob/master/chrome-extension-async.d.ts) for the promisified callbacks.

Install it with bower

```
bower install chrome-extension-async
```

Or [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chrome-extension-async)

```
npm i chrome-extension-async
```

Or [download](https://github.com/KeithHenry/chromeExtensionAsync/blob/master/chrome-extension-async.js) `chrome-extension-async.js` file and include it directly:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="chrome-extension-async.js"></script>
```

You can use this library with promises, which allows you to chain functions (rather than nest callbacks):

```
function whatever(anotherFolder, anotherFolder2) {
    return  chrome.bookmarks.create({title:'whatever2'}).
        then(parentFolder => 
            chrome.bookmarks.move(anotherFolder, {parentId: parentFolder.id})).
        then(() => 
            chrome.bookmarks.removeTree(anotherFolder2));
}
```

I strongly recommend that you use the (fairly new) `async` and `await` syntax, and TypeScript can transpile it to older versions of JS if you want. 
Then your code becomes:

```
async function whatever(anotherFolder, anotherFolder2) {
    const parentFolder = await chrome.bookmarks.create({title:'whatever2'});
    await chrome.bookmarks.move(anotherFolder, {parentId: parentFolder.id});
    await chrome.bookmarks.removeTree(anotherFolder2);
}
```

This does the same thing as the promise based code, but bubbles exceptions up and make it easier to use with logic flow (`if` branching logic can be messy even with promises).

Comment: nice - didn't know about that library - though I do think your recommendation about using async/await is unjustified as async/await is just Promise sugar and based on opinion rather than any real benefits in such a simple case :p

Comment: I take it your library "monkey patches" the existing functions?

Comment: @JaromandaX `async`/`await` isn't just syntactic sugar for promise, essentially it also creates a `function*` generator and a push observer for that generator that sends back the results of each Promise. It's not _just_ opinion - it leads to _much_ cleaner and more readable code and adds support for structures like `try`-`catch`-`finally`. For instance - if my example `async` function throws an exception it will bubble up to the main thread (despite me not including any explicit error handling) while the Promise-only equivalent would do nothing without an explicit `.catch()` at the end.

Comment: I wont get into a theological argument with you :p I see your point though - having wrapped my head around promises a few years ago, I like the "functional" aspect of using promises - again, that's opinion, so, not really relevant to SO :p

Comment: @JaromandaX fair enough :) Either way (`async`/`await` or `.then()`) is a huge improvement over callbacks.

Comment: @DanielHerr Interesting - a few minor changes to things like multi-variable callbacks and the code you'd write using either library would be very similar. In this specific case [`chrome-extension-async`](https://github.com/KeithHenry/chromeExtensionAsync) has the small advantage of including TypeScript definitions, but you can work around that. Both cover the `bookmarks` API and would help the OP.