# Chrome extension wait for tab creation and script inside tab (async issue)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a tab creation wait for completion before going on with the script but I haven't found a proper way to do it.

Here is a sample code that illustrate my problem:

```
for (x=0;x<5;x++)
{
console.log('start of my script');
chrome.tabs.create({ url: "myURL",  active: false }, function(tab) 
        { 
          console.log('Tab created: '+tab.id);
          // I do some scripting here
        }
console.log('end of my script');
}
```

Of course, what happens here is that I see:
Start of my script
end of my script
Tab created:...

I tried using "await" when calling the tab creation but it doesn't work and I can't remove the callback because I need it to get the id of the new tab.

Should I use a call back differently? Or is there another way to accomplish this?

Thanks!
Laurent

Comment: Simply register another listener in chrome.tabs.onUpdated, example: [Open a new Google Chrome tab and get the source](//stackoverflow.com/a/10162291)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript (typescript) Chrome extension, function callback as promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43223641/javascript-typescript-chrome-extension-function-callback-as-promises)

Answer (score 3):

Async code is much easier to read and write if you wrap the function with a `Promise` and call that instead.

There is [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chrome-extension-async) that will bundle all the Chrome APIs with Promise versions, but it's not a lot of code to do it one function at a time.

```
function chromeTabsCreateAsync(createProperties) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        chrome.tabs.create(createProperties, tab => {
            if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
                reject(new Error(chrome.runtime.lastError));
            } else {
                resolve(tab);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

This function can be called with `await` inside of an `async` function, and each iteration through the loop will pause until the value resolves.

```
async function main() {
    for (x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
        console.log('start of my script');
        let tab = await chromeTabsCreateAsync({ url: "about:blank", active: false });
        console.log('Tab created: ' + tab.id);
        console.log('end of my script');
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem, which is the fact that the callback is invoked right after the tab is created, not when its contents is loaded.

Comment: Hello I got closer to what I wanted with the script your provided, now I have I can create tabs one after the other but if I add a console.log in the chromeTabsCreateAsync to see what's happening, I see that the function keeps the ids of the previously opened tab on top of the tab it has recently created. If for example tab 1 is the first one and then tab 2 is the second one, I see console.log displaying 1 and 2 in the second iteration while the function is only called once for every id.